# How to print Node WebKit version

Tags: node-webkit

If I wanted to check which [Node WebKit](https://github.com/nwjs/nw.js) version I'm using, how would I do that from a command line?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To know the version of node-webkit in app so you can determine whether certain APIs are available, to get it you can use:

```
process.versions['node-webkit']
```

And to quickly know the node-webkit's version you are using now, you can type `nw:version` in the toolbar, then node-webkit would print the versions like:

```
node-webkit v0.3.5

node.js v0.8.14
```

If you are using Node Webkit Builder then use `nwbuild -v` or `nwbuild --version`

Comment: Thanks for the effort, but that does not answer my question.

Answer (score 6):

Launch node webkit from command line:

```
nw
```

Then type `nw:version` in the address bar to get the version number.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the effort. Seems that the nw version can't be read without starting the webkit. I'll accept @UtsavDawn answer b/c it was the first and essentially provides the same information as yours.

Answer (score 0):

`nw ls` from the command line gets a list of local cached nwjs versions, which may be helpful.